# Consumer Group between Cloud

Tags: apache-kafka

i want to ask about consumer group, but between cloud..

here is my example. i have 5 cloud server, lets say A B C D E F

Producer: A
Broker Cluster: B C
Consumer: D E F

Consumer with same group: D E

i want to ask, can we configure cloud D and E using same group? how the kafka broker notice the group from different cloud?

because when i start my consumer script(i use kafka/laravel), i just ran kafka:My-Topic , then the kafka consumer run.

1. When i use multiple cloud, i need to run each script in each cloud. i don't know what happen to my broker, can the broker cluster know the consumer group? or i need to decler each consumer group in broker?
2. Broker cluster is a replicate between broker right? can i setting broker B for D and E , then broker C for D E F ? does it count ae broker cluster?
3. What happend to broker cluster when i have multiple group with 1 consumer each group. Does my massage get consumed by 1 group, or multiple group will consume 1 massage?
4. is there any tutorial on how to create Key-Value for kafka? i need to store data inside kafka memory.

thx

Answer (score 0):

You simply give both apps the same group.id config. Doesn't really matter where they are running, as long as they can reach the brokers.

Yes, the brokers will know about the consumer groups that all clients are using.

No, you cannot/shouldn't assign specific brokers to clients. You might be able to assign partitions, but this is rarely a good idea for basic consumption.

If there are multiple, unique group names, they get all messages, regardless of the number of consumers in each group.

Kafka itself doesn't have "in memory" storage. I don't understand this last point, exactly. Your consumer can build a dictionary on its own when it processes messages, but obviously anything in-memory wouldn't be able to be distributed and queried across all consumers. Therefore, it might make sense to use something like KSQL to consume events into a lookup table, then use REST calls from php to it, rather than Kafka clients